# connect to microsoft access .mdb database using php in android

Tags: java, php, database, sqlite

I want to read from a **Microsoft Access** database by PHP on the server-side using android: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.esminis.server.php

```
try{
    $dbh = new PDO(
        "odbc:Driver = {Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};
        Dbq          = ".$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/aaa/aaa.mdb;
        Uid          = ;
        Pwd          = s;"
    );
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

But I get this error:

> 'SQLSTATE[01000] SQLDriverConnect: 0 [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't
>   open lib 'Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)' : file not found'